# Resizing a vector with resampling

Tags: r, vector, resize, resampling

I have the following problem which is not entirely a programming problem but I would like to have a programmed solution for it. I'm using R.

Consider the following vector

```
v <- c(2,3,6,1)
```

I want it to be resized to an arbitrary size but sum(v) should stay the same. Effectively, I want to stretch the vector. For example, by factor 2:

```
v2 <- c(1,1,1.5,1.5,3,3,0.5,0.5)
```

When the new vector is a multiple of the old one, we can just divide the elements. However, it should work also for others sizes which are not multiples of the original vector's size, e.g. 150.

I guess I could use something like linear interpolation for this but I can't think of a simple solution now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, just found a solution. I'm new to R and to math ;)

```
v <- seq(1,10)
```

This resizes the vector by interpolating the values:

```
v2 <- approx(v, n=33)$y
```

Next, we normalize to keep the sum:

```
norm <- sum(v)/sum(v2)
v3 <- v2 * norm
```

In this example, v3 will be

```
 [1] 0.3030303 0.3882576 0.4734848 0.5587121 0.6439394 0.7291667 0.8143939
 [8] 0.8996212 0.9848485 1.0700758 1.1553030 1.2405303 1.3257576 1.4109848
 [15] 1.4962121 1.5814394 1.6666667 1.7518939 1.8371212 1.9223485 2.0075758
 [22] 2.0928030 2.1780303 2.2632576 2.3484848 2.4337121 2.5189394 2.6041667
 [29] 2.6893939 2.7746212 2.8598485 2.9450758 3.0303030
```

Comment: no need to load `stats`, since it is already loaded by default.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the rep function to do this

```
rep(v,each=2)/2
```

> answer: [1] 1.0 1.0 1.5 1.5 3.0 3.0 0.5 0.5

Comment: This only works if the new vector's length is a multiple of the old vector's length. Also, this does not answer my question. I wanted to "stretch" the vector, instead of repeating the elements.

Comment: what do you mean by "This only works if the new vector's length is a multiple of the old vector's length", isn't it always going to be a multiple? can you give a specific example

Comment: In my answer the original vector's size is 10 while the new vector's size is 33. 33 is not a multiple of 10 because there is no integer i such as i * 10 = 33. Rep only takes integers as argument and I want to increase a vector's size by any kind of number.

Comment: can you give a full example with non integers. thanks

Comment: Look at my answer above. The original vector size is 10. The new vector size is 33. We increased the vector size by 3.3 and interpolated the existing data.